# Django SUB SUB domains

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-subdomains

How can i make django ALLOWED_HOST for sub sub domain.

For example: For subdomain I can use `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['.domain.com']` such that `a.domain.com,b.domain.com` etc.. will work. But I need `x.x.domain.com` where x value will change accordingly based on tenant such that `a.appointment.domain.com, b.appointment.domain.com, a.test.domain.com, b.test.domain.com`. How can I include x.x.domain.com (where both x changes accordingly) in my 'ALLOWED_HOSTS'

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['.appointment.domain.com','.test.domain.com']
```

Comment: You saved my day i was trying to add `*.localhost ` and it wasn't working